# DA100 - XPS 9350 support - Loki

Tags: release-loki, display, graphic-drivers, hdmi

All, I have a Dell XPS 13 series 9350, with eOS Loki ...

I bought the Dell DA-100 adapter with the sole purpose to extend my screen to a projector/TV via HDMI.  The NIC card on the DA-100 is detected, but the HDMI port is not.

Can I please get some help making my DA-100 adapter work ... if this is not possible, what USB (USB-c) device is supported under Loki to extend my screen to HDMI.

Thank you so much for the help.
Bill

Comment: well first thing first ... I have not had experience with this specific adapter ... but with the dell TB16 adapter ... I think you might need to install the displaylink software

Answer (score 0):

You should be good with USB-C adapter like this:
http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-adapter-usb-c-to-hdmi/apd/470-abmz/display-solutions

Comment: Honestly, I gave up on eOS, I moved over to Mint and have no issues since. I really liked elementary’s look and feel, but this issue, coupled with random screen refreshes to smaller screen sizes, random reboots, etc. I just got fed up.  I am 4 months into my Mint install and have had ZERO issues.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure this is a problem caused in eOS? I'm using a cheap USB c hub with my xps 13 (9350) and it's working perfectly fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to comment on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) from the asker. | >> [Help Center](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help) <<